# In SQL "WITH AS" clause is not working. is there any alternative way?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have one query, something like this:

```
    select col1,col2 from (
       with RESULTSET as (
       select * from t1 where rank_val=1 
      )  
      select  T1.col1, T1.col2    
      FROM RESULTSET T1, t88a, t88b
      where T1.col1=T88a.col1 and T88a.col2 = T1.col2
     AND T1.col2=T88b.col2 and T88b.col1 <> T1.col1
   ) where NOT (c1 IS NULL AND c2 IS NULL)   ORDER BY col1, col2;
```

I have a requirement where I need to use one outer `With As`, something like below:

```
WITH NEW AS(select col1,col2 from (
       with RESULTSET as (
       select * from t1 where rank_val=1 
      )  
      select  T1.col1, T1.col2    
      FROM RESULTSET T1, t88a, t88b
      where T1.col1=T88a.col1 and T88a.col2 = T1.col2
     AND T1.col2=T88b.col2 and T88b.col1 <> T1.col1
   ) where NOT (c1 IS NULL AND c2 IS NULL)   ORDER BY col1, col2)
   SELECT * FROM NEW;
```

Its giving me the exception:

```
 ORA-32034: unsupported use of WITH clause
 32034. 00000 -  "unsupported use of WITH clause"
```

How can I re write the query by removing the inner `With As`.

Comment: You can't nest those I think, but you can have multiple in a single `with` clause: `with ALIAS1 as (Query1), ALIAS2 as (Query2), ALIAS3 as (Query3) select ....`. Each of the queries can use the previously defined aliases.

Comment: @jarlh its Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0

Comment: To help you find documentation for them, these clauses are called "Common Table Expressions", commonly abbreviated to "CTE".

Answer (score 0):

Move all subqueries out, into a CTE. Something like this:

```
WITH
   resultset
   AS
      (SELECT *
         FROM t1
        WHERE rank_val = 1),
   temp
   AS
      (SELECT t1.col1, t1.col2
         FROM resultset t1
              JOIN t88a ON t88a.col1 = t1.col1
              JOIN t88b
                 ON     t88b.col2 = t1.col2
                    AND t88b.col1 <> t1.col1),
   new
   AS
      (SELECT col1, col2
         FROM temp
        WHERE NOT (    col1 IS NULL
                   AND col2 IS NULL))
  SELECT *
    FROM new
ORDER BY col1, col2;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define WITH either as separate section or as a part of subquery. Sample:

```sql
WITH
    tbl_1 AS    -- CTE 1
        (
            Select 'A' "LTTR", 1 "NMBR" From Dual Union ALL
            Select 'B' "LTTR", 2 "NMBR" From Dual Union ALL
            Select 'C' "LTTR", 3 "NMBR" From Dual 
        ),
    tbl_2 AS    -- CTE 2
        (
            Select 'A' "LTTR", 10 "NMBR" From Dual Union ALL
            Select 'B' "LTTR", 20 "NMBR" From Dual Union ALL
            Select 'C' "LTTR", 30 "NMBR" From Dual 
        )
Select
    t1.LTTR "LTTR", (t1.NMBR * t2.NMBR) - x.NMBR "CALCULATION"
From
    tbl_1 t1
Inner Join
    tbl_2 t2 ON(t2.LTTR = t1.LTTR)
Inner Join
    (WITH
        tbl_x AS    -- CTE 3
        (
            Select 'A' "LTTR",  5 "NMBR" From Dual Union ALL
            Select 'B' "LTTR", 10 "NMBR" From Dual Union ALL
            Select 'C' "LTTR", 15 "NMBR" From Dual 
        )
        Select * From tbl_x
    ) x ON(x.LTTR = t1.LTTR)
Order By 
    t1.LTTR
    
/*  R e s u l t :
LTTR CALCULATION
---- -----------
A              5 
B             30 
C             75
*/
```

It is better to keep them all together - it's easier to manage them later....
Regards...

Answer (score 0):

Your query can be rewritten as:

```sql
with RESULTSET as (
  select * from t1 where rank_val=1 
),
NEW AS(
  select col1,col2
  from (
    select  T1.col1, T1.col2    
    FROM    RESULTSET T1,
            t88a,
            t88b
    where   T1.col1=T88a.col1
    and     T88a.col2 = T1.col2
    AND     T1.col2=T88b.col2
    and     T88b.col1 <> T1.col1
  )
  where  NOT (col1 IS NULL AND col2 IS NULL)
  ORDER BY col1, col2
)
SELECT *
FROM   NEW;
```

However, you can simplify it down to:

```sql
SELECT T1.col1, T1.col2    
FROM   T1
       INNER JOIN t88a
       ON (   T1.col1=T88a.col1
          AND T88a.col2 = T1.col2 )
       INNER JOIN t88b
       ON (   T1.col2=T88b.col2
          AND T88b.col1 <> T1.col1 )
WHERE  t1.rank_val=1 
AND    (  t1.col1 IS NOT NULL
       OR t1.col2 IS NOT NULL )
ORDER BY col1, col2
```

But the `NOT NULL` checks in the `WHERE` clause are redundant as the `JOIN` conditions `T1.col1=T88a.col1` and `T88a.col2 = T1.col2` (etc.) will only ever be true when the values on both sides of the condition are `NOT NULL` so it can be simplified further to:

```sql
SELECT T1.col1, T1.col2    
FROM   T1
       INNER JOIN t88a
       ON (   T1.col1=T88a.col1
          AND T88a.col2 = T1.col2 )
       INNER JOIN t88b
       ON (   T1.col2=T88b.col2
          AND T88b.col1 <> T1.col1 )
WHERE  t1.rank_val=1 
ORDER BY col1, col2
```